# Inherit parents data for all the children in the xml data file

Tags: xml

I'm working on creating an `XML` file. For simplicity, let's say its school students data and all the students go to the same school. Below is the example `XML` with 3 students. As you can see, I need to repeat the same school data for all the students which are unnecessarily increasing the file length with increasing the students.

**Question:**

> To make the code compact, is there a way to declare the school data as some sort of global entity/node and all the students can inherit the same school data.

Thank you.

```
<students>

<student_1>
    <name>John</name>
    <DOB>1-1-2000</DOB>

    <school>
        <name>St Mary</name>
        <postcode>1234</postcode>
    </school>
</student_1>

<student_2>
    <name>Mark</name>
    <DOB>9-9-1998</DOB>

    <school>
        <name>St Mary</name>
        <postcode>1234</postcode>
    </school>
</student_2>

<student_3>
        <name>Steve</name>
        <DOB>7-7-2010</DOB>

    <school>
        <name>St Mary</name>
        <postcode>1234</postcode>
    </school>
</student_3>

</students>
```

Comment: There are many ways to do it. When I'm free, I'll try to describe it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it

```
<schools>
  <school>
    <name>St Mary</name>
    <postcode>1234</postcode>
    <students>
      <student>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>John</name>
        <DOB>1-1-2000</DOB>
      </student>
    </students>
  </school>
  <school>
    <name>St John</name>
    <postcode>1234</postcode>
    <students>
      <student>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Mark</name>
        <DOB>9-9-1998</DOB>
      </student>
      <student>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Steve</name>
        <DOB>7-7-2010</DOB>
      </student>
    </students>
  </school>
</schools>
```